# How to undo the last training step in a Session in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Is there a possibility to undo the last training step? For example when the loss value is 'NaN'.

```
...
for step in range(num_epoch):
   _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
   if np.isnan(loss_value):
      # something like: sess.undo_last()
      break
...
```

If there is such a method. Does it also work for Multi GPU trainings?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing, however you can do something like this.
In your model add:

```
loss = tf.check_numerics(loss)
```

This will throw an `InvalidArgument` exception if your loss becomes NaN or Inf. Since this is computed before you compute any backpropagation no weights are modified.
Your example code would look like:

```
for step in range(num_epoch):
   try:
     sess.run([train_op])
   except InvalidArgument:
     break
```

This will not help you though. Usually NaN or Inf loss means the model is already in a bad state. Try different activation functions or simpler models so that it doesn't go there.

Alternatively you can have checkpoints (save the model after every X steps) and look at picking a checkpoint before the error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I play around with the Cifar10 CNN Multi GPU Tensorflow Tutorial: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train. py. If I set the epochs too high, the loss value becomes NaN. Looking for a solution were only one Model is saved.